# MySQL inner join on meta fields type structure

Tags: mysql, database, inner-join

we have a `products` table with let's say has this structure,

```
id, name, price, status
```

and we have another table called `product_meta` which we created to store additional fields for products that we cannot add to the products table. product meta has a structure like

```
id, product_id, key, value
```

so let's say in the products table we have

```
id, name, price, status
1,  test, 100,   active
```

Then in the meta

```
id, product_id, key,           value
1,  1,          is_delivered,  yes
```

How do I write the query to inner join the products to meta if I want to select all products which don't have the `is_delivered` or if there is, the `is_delivered` should have a value of `no`

Comment: have you already attempted to write a query? can you please share?

Comment: `is_delivered` is a bit confusing.. you seem to describe it as a column while in your table sample it's a data value under the `key` column. Did you mean to say that _".. I want to select all products which the `key` column cell data is not `is_delivered` otherwise if the cell data `is_delivered`, the `values` column should have a cell data of `no`"_

Comment: By the way, I know that `product_meta` table is just an example but if you're creating a table, please try to avoid using [MySQL's reserved keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-K) as table and/or column name. Of course, you still can wrap them in backticks to be usable in queries, I'm just concern about the "what ifs" situation like "what if someone forgot to wrap them in backticks?", something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a left join, like so:

```
SELECT
  p.id, p.name -- add other fields when needed
FROM
  products AS p
LEFT JOIN
  product_meta AS m
  ON
    m.product_id = p.id AND m.key = 'is_delivered'
WHERE
  m.id IS NULL OR m.value = 'no'
```

By using the filter on [key] in the join you only get the records where "is_delivered" is set, so you can do exactly whay you want with the query-result: filter on "key not set" or "key has no".

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM products p
INNER JOIN product_meta m ON p.product_id = m.product_id
WHERE m.is_delivered IS NULL OR m.is_delivered ='no'
```

Please consider using `LIMIT`, `ORDER BY`, `GROUP BY` if necessary.

Comment: Wouldn't this assume there is always a record with the key "is_delivered"? Not saying that's wrong and it is what the OP asked, but still ...